# Assign ID to code without attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Can I assign an id to html code, without giving it any special attribute?
Specifically what I want is to be able to change my html code using JS.

I found that I can use this in html:

```
abc <b id="myID">def</b>
```

and then this in JS:

```
document.getElementById('myID').innerHTML = "123";
```

But this cause my text to be bold. I tried writing the following but it doesn't work:

```
abc <id="myID">def</id>
```

Comment: You meant not special attribute, but special TAG. @Darin Dimitrov is your answer.

Comment: Use `span` instead of `b`. `span` has neutral style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a div:

```
<div id="myID">def</div>
```

or a span:

```
<span id="myID">def</span>
```

and then:

```
document.getElementById('myID').innerHTML = "123";
```

Comment: div cause this part to be separated (new line) from other text. But span works great. Thanks!

Comment: @ Yanai [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-span-element.html#the-span-element) is probably the best for the use case in your question.

Comment: Yes, that's true. That's why I proposed `<span>` as well. But you could also make a div to behave like span using css: `<div id="myID" style="display:inline;">def</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your JS, the  tags stand for Bold. so If you don't want your text to appear bols then don't put it in  tag. use a  or

and if you want it to be displayed inline with the previous text then put it simply in a .

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using `<b>` is that it means “bold text” and hence causes the content to be bold by default (sometimes emulated by other highlighting by browsers when bolding cannot be used). Although you could mostly override this by setting `font-weight: normal` in CSS, it is better to use markup that has no effect on default rendering and functionality, or has *acceptable* effect on them.

The neutral, semantically empty inline markup element is `<span>`, white its block-level counterpart is `<div>`. In practice, the `<a>` element is semantically empty inline markup, too, when used without `href` attribute.

Comment: but using <b> tag then setting the font-weight to normal defeats the purpose of the bold tag.

Comment: <a> without href makes the text in different color, at least on my pc

Comment: @Yanai Ankri, that’s probably due to a style sheet that causes it. A style sheet could even define a color for `span`.